# Make ansible wait for server to start, without logging in

Tags: ansible, provisioning

When I provision a new server, there is a lag between the time I create it and it becomes available. So I need to wait until it's ready.

I assumed that was the purpose of the `wait_for` task:

hosts:

```
[servers]
42.42.42.42
```

playbook.yml:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: wait until server is up
    wait_for: port=22
```

This fails with `Permission denied`. I assume that's because nothing is setup yet.

*I expected* it to open an ssh connection and wait for the prompt - just to see if the server is up. But what *actually happens* is it tries to login.

Is there some other way to perform a wait that doesn't try to login?

Comment: Without the playbook (especially because of the missing `- hosts: ...`) there are ambiguities both in the answers and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you correctly stated, this task executes on the "to be provisioned" host, so ansible tries to connect to it (via ssh) first, then would try to wait for the port to be up. this would work for other ports/services, but not for 22 on a given host, since 22 is a "prerequisite" for executing any task on that host.

what you could do is try to `delegate_to` this task to the ansible host (that you run the PB) and add the `host` parameter in the `wait_for` task.

Example:

```
- name: wait until server is up
  wait_for: 
    port: 22
    host: <the IP of the host you are trying to provision>
  delegate_to: localhost
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining what the delegating to localhost means? I just tried it and it seems to work, but I'm unclear why?

Comment: about delegation, please see [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation). in a few words, instead of executing a task to the host your play refers to, you have ansible execute it on Y-host (for example, you want to run a `uri` task to fetch a page from the internet, but only certain hosts have access to the internet, you could delegate the task to them)

Comment: I read the docs but still don't understand why this works :-) :-) If the task fails because ansible can't login yet (it's a new server), why does delegating to localhost (the machine running the playbook) suddenly make it change behavior? Does this mean it executes `ssh` out-of-band, i.e. outside the ansible runtime?

Comment: the `wait_for` module only checks a server if the given port is up, and waits for it to become available. but to execute **any** task on **any** host, ansible has to connect to that host first. in your case, the ssh service is still not available, you cant run **any** task on it for as long as sshd is not running/properly configured. 

When you delegate this task to another host, ansible will successfully connect to it (no issues with sshd on that machine) and will just monitor the remote server, waiting for the 22 port to become available. hope its clear :)

Comment: Lol I'm really trying to understand you, but forgive me, I'm still an ansible newbie... are you saying it's checking whether sshd is running on localhost? My localhost doesn't run sshd (and what I really want to know is about the remote host not the local one). This works, but seems kinda magical right now :)

Comment: no probs :) from [ansible site](https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works): `Ansible works by connecting to your nodes and pushing out small programs, called "Ansible modules" to them. These programs are written to be resource models of the desired state of the system. Ansible then executes these modules (over SSH by default), and removes them when finished.` when you want to run `wait_for` task, ansible has to connect to that machine (via SSH), then execute the task. but your server doesnt have sshd yet, and fails (Permission denied) the task. plz ignore the "localhost & ssh" part.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Is there some other way to perform a wait that doesn't try to login?"*

A: It is possible to [wait_for_connection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_connection_module.html#wait-for-connection-waits-until-remote-system-is-reachable-usable). For example

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: wait until server is up
      wait_for_connection:
        delay: 60
        timeout: 300
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmmm If the server is already running, this doesn't seem to detect that, even if `delay` is set to 1. I don't think this works because it says `This module makes use of internal ansible transport (and configuration) and the ping/win_ping module to guarantee correct end-to-end functioning`, so it's using ping, which means it tries to login (which it can't do).

Comment: "...I don't think this works because it says" ?! "...  it's using ping, which means it tries to login" ?! Have you test it? It's "wait_for_connection". You're waiting for the connection. Right?

Comment: I tested it. I can't login even once the ssh port is ready, because it's an unprovisioned server without accounts (yet). That was the point of my question - to ensure the server is "up", but not actually login (which isn't possible, unless using root).

Comment: Well, "can't login" means you "can connect". When you "can connect" then `wait_for_connection` works as expected.

Comment: It doesn't work as expected as it doesn't suit the use case. The other answer does it properly, in that it will return a result once the port is available, this will simply timeout. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You said "I tested it. I can't login even once the ssh port is ready". Now you say "this will simply timeout".

Comment: Those two are not mutually exclusive. I cannot log in to an unprovisioned server unless I use the root password. I only want to know if it is "up", so I want to try connect, and wait for the ssh password prompt, if that is returned then the server is up. The other answer accomplishes that, it tells me whether the server is up or down within some timeout period. *This method actually tries to login*. So it "works" but not for this use case - it will just timeout. The other way will, within 60 seconds say, tell me that the server is up, or down, and *then let me continue running the playbook*.

Comment: I appreicate your answer, I'm just saying it doesn't apply to my use case. If the server were already provisioned, and *i could actually log in*, then this approach would be better and simpler.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself properly. Imagine this: the server is a *brand new* vps. There are no accounts other than root. You can only log in as root (you don't want to do that though). AND, you just want to know whether it's up. It takes 1-2 minutes for my vps to come alive. I just want to know when it's alive. That's the best explanation I can think of. Regards!

Comment: Your comments in this thread are misleading. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198418/discussion-between-vladimir-botka-and-lonix).